# How to access the GraphRestClient from Azure devops web extension?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I tired to invoke the Graph Groups API from Azure Devops web extension and its throwing the error "**Unable to contact the server. Please check your network connection and try again**"

Code Snippet used

import { getClient} from "azure-devops-extension-api/Common";

import { GraphRestClient } from "azure-devops-extension-api/Graph";

var client= getClient(GraphRestClient);

var groups = await client.getGroup("");

Am I missing some configuration ?

Comment: Above error is telling that you're not connected or you can't connect with the server. Please make sure that you can make the API call for the logged on user in Microsoft Graph explorer and they can access the Graph API programmatically - it's a prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

I have included the vso.tokens in vss-extension.json file. Its working now

```
"scopes": [
"vso.graph_manage",
"vso.tokens"
]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)